# Error: Same data looping with for loop inside while loop

Tags: php, for-loop, while-loop

I have a problem and it goes like this: When the user click the Submit button, the system must populate one Campaign with so many Teams and each Team is composed of  many members. So far this was my code:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT sched.cmsName, sched.team, sched.scheduleDate, sched.scheduleInput,emp.empNo FROM tbl_employeeschedules sched  
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_employees emp ON sched.cmsName = emp.cmsName 
                            WHERE sched.scheduleDate >= '$first' AND sched.scheduleDate < '$seven' AND sched.campaign='$_SESSION[campaign]' GROUP BY sched.team ORDER by sched.team, sched.cmsName") or die(mysql_error());


while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
     $team[$x] = $row['team'];
?>
<th>
    TEAM ID: 
</th>
<td colspan="9">
    <h5> <?php echo $team[$x];//if(isset($_POST['submit'])){if($_SESSION['team']=="Choose..."){echo "";}else{echo $_SESSION['team'];}}else{echo "";}  ?>  </h5>
</td>

<?php

$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT sched.team, sched.cmsName, sched.scheduleDate, sched.scheduleInput,emp.empNo FROM tbl_employeeschedules sched  
                            LEFT OUTER JOIN tbl_employees emp ON sched.cmsName = emp.cmsName 
                            WHERE sched.scheduleDate >= '$first' AND sched.scheduleDate <= '$seven' AND sched.campaign='$_SESSION[campaign]' AND sched.team='$team[$x]' GROUP BY sched.cmsName") or die(mysql_error());

$y =1;
 while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2))
{
    $empNo[$y] = $row2['empNo'];
    $agent[$y] = $row2['cmsName'];
    echo $agent[$y];
    $y++;
 }

for($y=1;$y<=count($empNo); $y++)
{

$query2 = mysql_query("SELECT scheduleInput,cmsName FROM tbl_employeeschedules WHERE cmsName='$agent[$y]'  AND scheduleDate = '$first' AND campaign='$_SESSION[campaign]' AND team='$team[$x]'") or die(mysql_error());
                if(mysql_num_rows($query2) == 0)
                {
                    $monday[$y] = "no schedule"; 
                }
                else
                {
                    while($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2))
                    {
                        $monday[$y] = $row2['scheduleInput'];
                    }
                }

                $query3 = mysql_query("SELECT scheduleInput,cmsName FROM tbl_employeeschedules WHERE cmsName='$agent[$y]'  AND scheduleDate = '$second' AND campaign='$_SESSION[campaign]' AND team='$team[$x]'") or die(mysql_error());
                if(mysql_num_rows($query3) == 0)
                {
                    $tuesday[$y] = "no schedule"; 
                }
                else
                {
                    while($row3 = mysql_fetch_array($query3))
                    {
                        $tuesday[$y] = $row3['scheduleInput'];
                    }
                }

                $query4 = mysql_query("SELECT scheduleInput,cmsName FROM tbl_employeeschedules WHERE cmsName='$agent[$y]'  AND scheduleDate = '$third' AND campaign='$_SESSION[campaign]' AND team='$team[$x]'") or die(mysql_error());
                if(mysql_num_rows($query4) == 0)
                {
                    $wednesday[$y] = "no schedule"; 
                }
                else
                {
                    while($row4 = mysql_fetch_array($query4))
                    {
                        $wednesday[$y] = $row4['scheduleInput'];
                    }
                }

                $query5 = mysql_query("SELECT scheduleInput,cmsName FROM tbl_employeeschedules WHERE cmsName='$agent[$y]'  AND scheduleDate = '$fourth' AND campaign='$_SESSION[campaign]' AND team='$team[$x]'") or die(mysql_error());
                if(mysql_num_rows($query5) == 0)
                {
                    $thursday[$y] = "no schedule"; 
                }
                else
                {
                    while($row5 = mysql_fetch_array($query5))
                    {
                        $thursday[$y] = $row5['scheduleInput'];
                    }
                }

                $query6 = mysql_query("SELECT scheduleInput,cmsName FROM tbl_employeeschedules WHERE cmsName='$agent[$y]'  AND scheduleDate = '$fifth' AND campaign='$_SESSION[campaign]' AND team='$team[$x]'") or die(mysql_error());
                if(mysql_num_rows($query6) == 0)
                {
                    $friday[$y] = "no schedule"; 
                }
                else
                {
                    while($row6 = mysql_fetch_array($query6))
                    {
                        $friday[$y] = $row6['scheduleInput'];
                    }
                }

                $query7 = mysql_query("SELECT scheduleInput,cmsName FROM tbl_employeeschedules WHERE cmsName='$agent[$y]'  AND scheduleDate = '$six' AND campaign='$_SESSION[campaign]' AND team='$team[$x]'") or die(mysql_error());
                if(mysql_num_rows($query7) == 0)
                {
                    $saturday[$y] = "no schedule"; 
                }
                else
                {
                    while($row7 = mysql_fetch_array($query7))
                    {
                        $saturday[$y] = $row7['scheduleInput'];
                    }
                }

                $query8 = mysql_query("SELECT scheduleInput,cmsName FROM tbl_employeeschedules WHERE cmsName='$agent[$y]'  AND scheduleDate = '$seven' AND campaign='$_SESSION[campaign]' AND team='$team[$x]'") or die(mysql_error());
                if(mysql_num_rows($query8) == 0)
                {
                    $sunday[$y] = "no schedule"; 
                }
                else
                {
                    while($row8 = mysql_fetch_array($query8))
                    {
                        $sunday[$y] = $row8['scheduleInput'];
                    }
                }


            echo"
                <tr>
                <td class='id'> $empNo[$y] </td>
                <td class='agent' colspan='3'> $agent[$y] </td>
                <td> <img class='monday' src='images/grayBox.JPG' style='height:10px;width:8px;'/> $monday[$y] </td>
                <td> <img class='tuesday' src='images/grayBox.JPG' style='height:10px;width:8px;'/> $tuesday[$y] </td>
                <td> <img class='wednesday' src='images/grayBox.JPG' style='height:10px;width:8px;'/> $wednesday[$y] </td>
                <td> <img class='thursday' src='images/grayBox.JPG' style='height:10px;width:8px;'/> $thursday[$y] </td>
                <td> <img class='friday' src='images/grayBox.JPG' style='height:10px;width:8px;'/> $friday[$y] </td>
                <td> <img class='saturday' src='images/grayBox.JPG' style='height:10px;width:8px;'/> $saturday[$y] </td>
                <td> <img class='sunday' src='images/grayBox.JPG' style='height:10px;width:8px;'/> $sunday[$y] </td>
                </tr>
                ";
        }
$x++; 
    }
```

In this code: The campaign and team is showing up correctly but the member is showing the same for the rest of the rows.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: There seems to be a lot of places for factorization: Why is the same query repeated 8 times?

Comment: Yes i am aware of this Sir @tyteen4a03, this is the last project/system that company will use with mysql. The next projects would be mysqli :)

Comment: It is used for 8 times because i need different conditions here for 8 diff. days. The first query that has a schedule='$first' is showing up the schedule of that specific member on Monday. And the second query is for tuesday and so on and so for..

Comment: You should fetch all data with one query and sort them out in PHP.

Comment: This problem already solved. Thank you :)